# How to make an array containing function pointers?

Tags: c

I have been under the requirement where I need to have an array of function pointers. I tried multiple approaches but didn't work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
void fun()
{
printf("fun function");
}
size_t *arr[]={fun};
int main()
{
(*arr[0])();
return 0;
}
```

It gives the error: called object is not a function or function pointer

Comment: Show what you have tried.

Comment: [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [mcve]...